# how to check the date using internet in matlab?

Tags: matlab

when using date command in matlab, i get the system current date. is there a way to get the current date using internet in matlab? the link i've given is similar to this question but that question was asked for vb, and i'm trying to do this thing in matlab.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198527/how-to-check-the-real-date-time-through-an-internet-connection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB Code based on `urlread` to get current date using internet (URL) and with couple of bounding keys (to find the date string) -

```
URL = 'http://time.is/';
key1 = 'title="Click for calendar">';
key2 = '</h2>';

data = urlread(URL);
start_ind = strfind(data,key1);
data1 = data(start_ind:end);
off_stop_ind = strfind(data1,key2);
current_date = data(start_ind+ numel(key1):start_ind + off_stop_ind(1)-2)
```

Output at my location -

```
current_date =
Saturday, September 6, 2014, week 36
```

---

If you would like to have it in the DD-MM-YYYY format, use this -

```
date_split = strsplit(current_date,',')
current_date1 = datestr(strcat(date_split(2),date_split(3)))
```

Output -

```
current_date1 =
06-Sep-2014
```

Comment: yup, its fine :)
but if u don't mind, can u do a little change in it? the output should be like 06-Sep-2014
sorry, i'm new to programming and very very new to matlab, so i know i'm asking a bit foolish things, but i'd to ask it, coz i'm not able to do it right now.. 
anyways thanks @Divakar :)